# Numeric conversion get-request with curl e- problem

Tags: php

Curl Get-request return numeric vales with e-, but I need json string with normal numeric format or convert numeric e- to string full numeric value

```php
<?php


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.huobi.pro/market/tickers");

$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($json, true);

$curr_pairs = array("iotabtc","manabtc");

foreach ($obj['data'] as $tick_s){
    $huobi_curr_pair = $tick_s['symbol'];

    if (in_array($huobi_curr_pair, $curr_pairs,true)){
        $tick_string = json_encode($tick_s);
        echo $tick_string;  
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: can you show an example and the expected result ?

Comment: result: {"open":7.0e-5,"close":6.912e-5,"low":6.871e-5,"high":7.058e-5,"amount":2194983.                                                                                                      6936793807,"count":9119,"vol":153.38732516649992,"symbol":"iotabtc"}

Comment: expected result: {"open":0.000007,"close":0.00006925,"low":0.00006871,"high":0.00007058,"amount":2194983.                                                                                                      6936793807,"count":9119,"vol":153.38732516649992,"symbol":"iotabtc"}

Comment: what varaible contains this value in the code above ?

Comment: this $tick_string

Comment: this is not a valid json format i think

Comment: can you show the $tick_s

Comment: @Dmitry What is problematic about the `e-` notation of your floating point values? The value is the same, regardless if you use `e-` notation or write `0.00006912`. And when the JSON string is decode again you get the same correct value. When it is a display issue you can just use `number_format()` when you display the value.

Comment: @Progman you are right, e- notation well decoded to full number format. I tried decode json in database and result is ok